# Run Linux command as predefined user

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have created a shell script to start a `server` program.

```
startup.sh  start
```

When above command will executes, it will try starts the `server` as `adminuser`. To achieve this my script has written like this.

```
SUBIT="su - adminuser -c "
SERVER_BOX_COMMAND_A="Server"

##############
# Function to start cluster

function start(){

   $SUBIT "$SERVER_BOX_COMMAND_A"

}
```

When i execute the command it asks for password. Is there any other way to do this so, it will not ask for password.

I have seen this behavior in Jboss startup script provided on jboss. That script changes the user to `jboss` and then starts the jboss server. I wanted my script to behave same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something what you ask is not possible.

The jboss script is designed to

1. Start as root
2. Switch to jboss user which has less privilages

But what you ask is

1. Start as a non-privilaged user
2. Switch to admin/root which has **more** privilages.

This is why you will **always** need a password no matter the command you try.

Is there any specific reason that your server needs elevated privilages?

Comment: you mean to say if i run my script from root, it will work as I like it to run?

Comment: What he describes is exactly what is given by the setuid bit.

Answer (score 3):

If you are root, just use [sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

```
$1 sudo -u adminuser startup.sh start
```

Comment: Hi unwind, Can you please describe the command? I think it will `su` to adminuser and then call the script. Am i right?

Comment: `sudo`, not `su` (though you can use `su` too, as `su -c`, but these are different commands with different purposes).

Comment: Above command still asks for the password? :(

Comment: @vijay.shad: The man page I linked (click the command name in my answer) provides plenty of explanation. You really shouldn't be getting a password prompt if you're running sudo as root. Verify that you are.

Answer (score 1):

Like JBoss, you could check to see if you are the target user before running your command.

```
TARGET_USER='adminuser'
SUBIT="su - adminuser -c "
SERVER_BOX_COMMAND_A="Server"

##############
# Function to start cluster

function start(){

   if [[ `whoami` == "$TARGET_USER" ]]
   then
      $SERVER_BOX_COMMAND_A
   else
      $SUBIT "$SERVER_BOX_COMMAND_A"
   fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the setuid bit. Make the owner of the file the user you want to run the script as and then make your script setuid.

Note that this can be a security risk so make sure that user has only the permissions needed. After all, an unprivileged user can run that script, right?

**EDIT: Don't make scripts setuid. Your jboss example is a program that drops privileges, not a script.**

Comment: Most Unix implementations do not allow setuid scripts.  See for example http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html .

Comment: You should never have a script that's setuid and many systems won't allow it.

Comment: Aah yes--setuid is for programs, not scripts.